# Creating Custom URLs in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I'm in the process of writing a blogging software, as a learning excercise.  Everything is going well, except I'm not sure how to create user-fieldly, SEO friendly URLs.

For instance:

```
http://myblogsite.com/blogs/default.aspx?ID=12
```

should be something more user friendly:

```
http://myblogsite.com/blogs/how-to-create-custom-urls-in-asp-net
```

I did look around, but couldn't find anything helpful.  I want to create a permanent url and people can share and link to on otehr websites.  On existing blog applications, it is referred to as "slug", I believe.  But, I'm not sure how it works in Asp.Net.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [URL routing in ASP.Net 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). For .Net 3.5 and lower the solutions are limited and more complicated, especially with IIS 6 because of how it handles extensionless requests.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "blogs/{blogName}",
        "~/blogs/default.aspx");
```

But you'd have to change ID to name and make it distinct. Also be careful of `/` slipping into it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [IIS7 URLRewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).